# Understanding the total time complexity of code

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

```c
//test:constant
if(length()==0){
    return false; //then part:constant
}

else{ //else part:(constant+constant)*n
    for(int n=0; n<length();n++){
        //another if: constant+constant(no else part)
        if(!list[n].equals(otherList.list[n]))
            //constant
            return false;     
    }
}
```

Total time= c0+c1+(c2+c3)*n

While I'm able to figure out the complexity of the given code will be O(n), I'm not able to understand how the author of the code arrived to the total time as
c0+c1+(c2+c3)*n

In my opinion it should be simply cn. Please help me understanding.

Comment: technically, your opinion and author's make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand:

```
if (length() == 0) { // (c0)
    return false; 
} else { // (c1)
    for (int n = 0; n < length(); n++) { // Managing for loop: (c3)
        if(!list[n].equals(otherList.list[n])) // whole if: (c4)
            return false;     
    }
}
```

Thus why he gets to c0 + c1 + (c2 + c3) * n. However, I'm not sure about c1 because a else is simply a goto. It could be counted I guess. Also, this could be summarized as c0 + c1 * n.

Comment: I too tried to look that way. However, whenever there is If-else condition, ideally we should consider either of the subsequent statements which follow 'If' or 'else' for arriving at the time complexity for  the WORST condition. So in that way, the total time should have been c4*n.

Also, please note I think the steps like 'if' and 'else' are not considered for for calculating time complexity. Only the statements that follows then are taken in consideration.
Hence, taking  'if (length() == 0)' as, c0 and  'else' as c1 might not be correct.

Comment: Testing a condition clearly takes time. If you have an if statement in a for loop, I guarantee you that it will be considered in the big O. Now, the else can be overlooked, since it's only a goto.